# My computer beeps while copying files

Tags: ubuntu, audio, file-copy

Whenever I create disk activity on my memory stick, my headphones create very annoying beeps at various notes. It doesn't happen with my in built speakers, and it hasn't happened before. I'm on Ubuntu 13.10, how can I stop this happening

Comment: Umm. That's a new one. A stopgap might be to disable beeps but you should try and find the underlying problem. Does it only happen with `cp`? Only on specific directories or partitions? Do `mv` or `rsync` also cause it? How about saving/creating files?

Comment: I think it's with all disk activity. And it's not the standard error beep, it's something else... I've had it on Lubuntu before, but not for a long time.

Comment: try another pair of headphones, also do you have a separate headphone jack. Is this a laptop, or do you have a front port for the headphones? If you are using a front port try plugging the headphones in the back to rule out the source of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your disk is not dying?

Comment: @terdon No I don't think it is :)

Comment: Try muting all your audio *inputs*. Maybe one of them is picking up electrical noise inside the computer, and feeding it back to the headphones. [This sounds to me more like an electrical problem than a software one.]

Comment: @Mateo Yes it's a laptop, no I don't have a front port, my headphones as they're very good quality and it only happens with disk activity, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @Mateo actually, turns out it was only on my memory stick so not sorted :( What now?

Comment: @derobert No, unfortunately that doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried using a DIFFERENT memory stick, like a name-brand memory stick?  Same issue?  My guess is that whomever made your memory stick didn't care too much about RF emissions & it probably wouldn't pass FCC RF emissions testing.  Is it a cheap no-name memory stick?  Or perhaps a forgery of a name-brand, bought on some discount website that "inexplicably" sells name-brand merchandise for about 20% of what it normally costs?

Comment: @phonetagger no I've only tried this one, it's a 4GB one I got from WHSmith, but the brand name has rubbed off. I'm pretty sure it's HP or something.

Comment: @illuminÉ lol, or are you serious?

Comment: @illuminÉ Thank you, I understand now, but it still made me laugh!

Comment: What I meant is that if you've identified a piece of defective electronics, the worst thing you can do is use it with something that works. You also don't want to leave it around and reuse it later on having forgotten about it... you're welcome!